# Java Me platform issues in NetBeans

Tags: java, mobile, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-plugins

I have installed Netbeans 8.0 that comes with pre installed Java ME plugin. 
Now when I tried to create a new Java ME project it said `No Java ME Platform found. Please add at least one`

Also, the field "Java ME platform" was blank. So I clicked on `Manage platforms` and added `Java ME CDLC Emulator Platform` and gave the path to JAVA ME SDK.
It discovered the platform and added the devices.

After doing this, the field "Java ME platform" is still blank and I'm not able to select the Java Me platform.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem during installation on a new PC.
I'm developing for J2ME, CLDC 1.1, MIDP 2.1,
but I just couldn't manage to add a platform that would allow me to compile and run my app on an emulator.

The PC is a 64-bit PC, and I'm using the SDK 3.4, which is 32 bit
so finally I installed Virtual Box, Windows 7 32-bit as guest, and finally it worked
- installed first java jdk-8u25-windows-i586
- then netbeans 8 netbeans-8.0.1-windows
- once netbeans installed, activated java me plug in, there was no need to install it, it's pre-installed
- then java me sdk 3.4 oracle-jmesdk-3-4-rr-win32-bin
- then in netbeans, tools - java platforms, add the platform java me 3.4 just installed

Now I can emulate my app again

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of projects available `Java ME embedded` and `Java ME`. The `Java ME CDLC Emulator Platform` is used for `Java ME` projects.

One thing you should check is the activation step as described here: https://netbeans.org/kb/73/javame/cdc-quickstart.html

For my case I had the EE version of Netbeans 8.0 so I wen to the start page then to plugins and downloaded everything that had to do with JME. I also had to download SDK `Java ME SDK 3.2`.

I also downloaded the plugins for Netbeans (even though I did the plugin installation through the IDE) `Java ME SDK 3.2 Plugins for NetBeans` from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html. Then went to Tools->Plugins selected the Downloaded tab and finally Add PLugins ...

**UPDATE - Tried with NetBeans 8.0 All (contains JAVA ME)**

Even after activating the plugins I still had to download `Java ME SDK 3.2 Plugins for NetBeans`. Only then the IDE is offering me **Java ME** when I click at new project.

What I did:

**1) Activate Java ME plugin, restart the IDE:**

[image: activate java me]

**2) Install `Java ME SDK 3.2`**

**3) Go to Tools add platform. Restart IDE just in case. Still offered only *Java ME embedded* as project:**

[image: Java ME embedded]

**4) Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html and download the plugins for the Netbeans IDE. Unzip the file and install them (press ctrl-a to select all the nbm files and click open):**

[image: install netbeans plugins for Java ME]

**5) Click install. This will install everything needed and it will prompt you to restart the IDE:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**6) Restart the IDE and there it is:**

[image]

[image]

[image]